# Convert an image to binary format using xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode4.5

In my app .I have an UIImageView that is browsed .I dont know whether the image is jpeg or png.

I want to convert that image(What ever the format) to binary format

Iam new to this concept. help me

how can i send the image in imageview to server in binaryformat

Comment: An image already is composed of binary data.

Comment: how can i send the image in imageview to server in binaryformat

Answer (score 0):

1. Your [UIImageView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) has a [Image](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIImage).
2. You can get the image data by using:

   NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(yourImage, 0.9);

   or

   NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(yourImage);
3. Afther you get your image data you have to make a post request to your server. You can use [NSURLConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003755) or any third party framework like  [AFNetworking](http://afnetworking.com/) for example.